# bad argument in call to crypto:aes_cfb_128_crypt

Tags: erlang

This is the code snippet at line 461 which is giving badarg error ,please help me solve this error guys.

```
ejabberd_odbc:escape(base64:encode(crypto:aes_cfb_128_encrypt(<<"abcdefghabcdefgh">>, <<"12345678abcdefgh">>, xml:element_to_binary(NewPacket)))),
```

**Log:**

bad argument in call to crypto:aes_cfb_128_crypt(<<"abcdefghabcdefgh">>, <<"12345678abcdefgh">>, <<">, true) in mod_offline:'-store_offline_msg/6-fun-2-'/2 line 225

Comment: The code you gave is not even a whole line, `lists:flatmap` is not even closed. In addition, what is `XML`? What is function `str:str`? Many details are missing in order to be able to help.

Comment: You probably want to add to the question code for this function as well: `{file,"src/mod_offline.erl"},
{line,462}`

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I like about functional languages is that you generally have an easier time reproducing errors in a controlled environment. In your case, it seems like

```
base64:decode(XML)
```

is the call that's failing, so you should write

```
io:format("XML=~p~n", [XML]),
base64:decode(XML)
```

the first line will print out the contents of `XML` in Erlang syntax, and the second line will fail when you get to the bad input.

Once you see the string you're trying to decode, the problem will probably be obvious (it's not a string or it's not a base64 string). If it *is* a correctly-encoded base64 string, then you can post that problem as a StackOverflow question and get a more useful response.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel .